# vue2 how add and observe changes element in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, two-way

I can't change child by type something  in the input;
how to observe the input and make it affected the child .
and Verify if there is a name for each child

the  js:

```
     $(function () {
       var person = {
           name: '',
           children: ['Please enter a name']
       }

       var vm = new Vue({
           el: "#example",
           data: person,
           methods: {
               addChild: function (index) {
                   this.children.splice(index+1, 0, ""); //
               },
               removeChild: function (index) {
                   this.children.splice(index , 1)
               },
               getData: function () {
                   console.log(this.children);
               }
           }    
       })

   })
```

the html part:

```
<ul >
    <li v-for="(child,index) in children">
        the child at <span>{{ index }}</span> is <span >{{ child }}</span>
        <input v-model = "child">
        <button @click="addChild(index)">newChild</button>
        <button v-on:click="removeChild(index)">X</button>

    </li>
</ul>
    <button v-on:click="getData">watch data</button>
    <div>{{ $data | json }} </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$index` has [been deprecated in Vue 2.x](https://vuejs.org/guide/migration.html#index-and-key-deprecated).  Instead, you can assign a variable to the index as part of the `v-for` directive:

```
<li v-for="(child,index) in person.children">
    the child at <span>{{ index }}</span> is <span >{{ child }}</span>
    <input v-model = "person.children[index]">
    <button @click="addChild(index)">newChild</button>
    <button v-on:click="removeChild(index)">X</button>
</li>
```

**UPDATED**

Ok, I see what you're doing now. You can set the `v-model` to an expression of the object to bind to.  In your case, it's the child element at a specific index so notice how I changed the `input`'s `v-model` binding to `person.children[index]`.

I also changed the `data` option to be an object with a single `person` property.  This made the bindings into the children array work.

Here's the [complete working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psteele/tpb76zf1/).

Comment: thanks, can I use just an array of items   like ['child1','child2' ] instead of arrray of object

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: the index works , but the input can't affect the data,why it does.'t work

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  Are you getting an error?  Your code shows to method: `addChild` and `removeChild` -- if one of those is generating an error, please include which one it is.

Comment: makes two-way binding between input and single child ，the bind doesn't work，I can only add '' into children

Comment: have you noticed that the name input can immediately affect the name，

Comment: have you noticed that the name input can immediately affect the name.

Comment: sorry for so  many comments , the dom doesn't  immediately refresh when I type something in  child input  .it only refresh after I type in the name input ot click "add child" button